# Solar System in Python

Tags: python, simulation, turtle-graphics, astronomy

I am trying to create a very simplified model of Solar System in Python, using the [turtle](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle) library. Earth, Earth's spacecraft, Mars and at the center of coordinate system - Sun. I've found a very helpful [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1GT0jGBR-I), that shows easiest way to draw an ellipse around the centre of mass, although, I see many disadvantages in it. For example, the math of the equations is illogical in here.

Despite that, I don't have the problem with the unrealistic numbers in this video (like mysterious 1000). I just need to create simplified orbits, they don't have to be accurate to those in real world, so the code from video mentioned above should be enough. At the beggining I've created a simulation with just Mars and Earth orbiting the Sun:

```
import turtle
import math

mars = turtle.Turtle()
earth = turtle.Turtle()

def way_to_orbit(x,y, object, colors):
    object.dot(50, "yellow")
    object.color("white")
    object.fillcolor(colors)
    object.shape("circle")
    object.penup()
    object.setposition(x, y)
    object.pendown()


def ellipse(object1, object2):

    loop = True
    object2_xvel = 0
    object2_yvel = 1
    object1_xvel = 0
    object1_yvel = 1

    while loop:
        object2_xvel += math.cos(math.radians(object2.towards(0, 0))) * (1000 / (object2.xcor() ** 2 + object2.ycor() ** 2))
        object2_yvel += math.sin(math.radians(object2.towards(0, 0))) * (1000 / (object2.xcor() ** 2 + object2.ycor() ** 2))
        object2.setposition(object2.xcor() + object2_xvel, object2.ycor() + object2_yvel)

        object1_xvel += math.cos(math.radians(object1.towards(0, 0))) * (1000 / (object1.xcor() ** 2 + object1.ycor() ** 2))
        object1_yvel += math.sin(math.radians(object1.towards(0, 0))) * (1000 / (object1.xcor() ** 2 + object1.ycor() ** 2))
        object1.setposition(object1.xcor() + object1_xvel, object1.ycor() + object1_yvel)



way_to_orbit(620, 0, mars, "red")
way_to_orbit(375, 0, earth, "blue")

ellipse(mars, earth)


turtle.done()
```

Output was a moving simulation with two planets:

Output with planets only

[image]

Everything was fine, so I've decided to add the spacecraft, orbiting the Earth. In this case, Earth (`object2`) was the center of the mass for the spacecraft (`object3`) in `ellipse` function:

```
import turtle
import math

mars = turtle.Turtle()
earth = turtle.Turtle()
spacecraft = turtle.Turtle()



def way_to_orbit(x,y, object, colors):
    object.dot(50, "yellow")
    object.color("white")
    object.fillcolor(colors)
    object.shape("circle")
    object.penup()
    object.setposition(x, y)
    object.pendown()


def ellipse(object1, object2, object3):

    loop = True
    object2_xvel = 0
    object2_yvel = 1
    object1_xvel = 0
    object1_yvel = 1
    object3_xvel = 0
    object3_yvel = 1
    a = 0
    while loop:
        object2_xvel += math.cos(math.radians(object2.towards(0, 0))) * (1000 / (object2.xcor() ** 2 + object2.ycor() ** 2))
        object2_yvel += math.sin(math.radians(object2.towards(0, 0))) * (1000 / (object2.xcor() ** 2 + object2.ycor() ** 2))
        object2.setposition(object2.xcor() + object2_xvel, object2.ycor() + object2_yvel)

        object1_xvel += math.cos(math.radians(object1.towards(0, 0))) * (1000 / (object1.xcor() ** 2 + object1.ycor() ** 2))
        object1_yvel += math.sin(math.radians(object1.towards(0, 0))) * (1000 / (object1.xcor() ** 2 + object1.ycor() ** 2))
        object1.setposition(object1.xcor() + object1_xvel, object1.ycor() + object1_yvel)

        # object3_xvel += math.cos(math.radians(object3.towards(object2.xcor(), object2.ycor()))) * (1000 / ((object3.xcor()**2)-(object2.xcor()**2)) + ((object3.ycor()**2)-(object2.ycor()**2)))
        # object3_yvel += math.sin(math.radians(object3.towards(object2.xcor(), object2.ycor()))) * (1000 / ((object3.xcor()**2)-(object2.xcor()**2)) + ((object3.ycor()**2)-(object2.ycor()**2)))
        # object3.setposition(object3.xcor() + object3_xvel, object3.ycor() + object3_yvel)


way_to_orbit(620, 0, mars, "red")
way_to_orbit(375, 0, earth, "blue")
way_to_orbit(376, 0, spacecraft, "green")

ellipse(mars, earth, spacecraft)


turtle.done()
```

Output was insane: 
Output with spacecraft

[image]

I have no idea what happened in here. I just want the moving simulation, as simple as possible, of 2 objects orbiting around the Sun and the satellite for one of them. The laws of physics are secondary in this case, all of this is made for other purpose.

1. So, how can I fix the path of the turtle simulating the spacecraft/satellite?
2. Is there any easier or faster way to create such simulation in Python?
3. Could somebody explain for me the methods used for ellipse drawing used in the video?

Comment: first use `print()` to see values in variables - it should help to understant problem. Maybe to rotate around planet you would have to: move coordinates to (0,0) (substract planet's position from spaceraft's position), rotate around (0,0), move back to old place (add planet's position to spaceraft's position),

Answer (score 0):

I don't know good solution but I found two problems and one solution.

First: `earth` and `mars` move around `sun` which is not moving but `spacecraft` moves around `earth` which is moving. You could use `earth` `xvel` `yvel` to move `spacecraft` before you calculate `xvel` `yvel` for `spacercraft` - this way you will get effect like with moving `spacecraft` around not-moving `earth`

```
object3.setposition(object3.xcor() + object2_xvel, object3.ycor() + object2_yvel)
```

Second: if I uses `1000/constant` for `spacecraft` then its move looks good. Normal calculation makes inaccurate results and they change a little in every move but finally it change too much and `spacecraft` moves away. I don't know better solution for this problem.

`spacecraft` distance to `earth` is changing on screen because it moves on ellipse, not circle, but it keeps close to `earth` all time.

```
while loop:
    distance = 1000 / (object2.xcor()**2 + object2.ycor()**2)
    rad = math.radians(object2.towards(0, 0))
    object2_xvel += math.cos(rad) * distance
    object2_yvel += math.sin(rad) * distance
    object2.setposition(object2.xcor() + object2_xvel, object2.ycor() + object2_yvel)

    distance = (1000 / (object1.xcor() ** 2 + object1.ycor() ** 2))
    rad = math.radians(object1.towards(0, 0))
    object1_xvel += math.cos(rad) * distance
    object1_yvel += math.sin(rad) * distance
    object1.setposition(object1.xcor() + object1_xvel, object1.ycor() + object1_yvel)

    # move `spacecraft` with `earth`
    object3.setposition(object3.xcor() + object2_xvel, object3.ycor() + object2_yvel)

    #distance = ( (object3.xcor()**2)-(object2.xcor()**2) ) + ( (object3.ycor()**2)-(object2.ycor()**2) )
    distance = 1000/3441 # constant value
    rad = math.radians(object3.towards(object2.xcor(), object2.ycor()))
    object3_xvel += math.cos(rad) * distance
    object3_yvel += math.sin(rad) * distance
    object3.setposition(object3.xcor() + object3_xvel, object3.ycor() + object3_yvel)
```

I set bigger distance from `spacecraft` to `earth` because `spacecraft` elipse was very flat and it moved through `earth`

```
way_to_orbit(375, 0, earth, "blue")
way_to_orbit(436, 0, spacecraft, "green")
```

---

Full code

```
import turtle
import math

mars = turtle.Turtle()
earth = turtle.Turtle()
spacecraft = turtle.Turtle()


def way_to_orbit(x,y, object, colors):
    object.dot(50, "yellow")
    object.color("white")
    object.fillcolor(colors)
    object.shape("circle")
    object.penup()
    object.setposition(x, y)
    object.pendown()


def ellipse(object1, object2, object3):

    loop = True
    object2_xvel = 0
    object2_yvel = 1
    object1_xvel = 0
    object1_yvel = 1
    object3_xvel = 0
    object3_yvel = 1
    a = 0

    while loop:
        distance = 1000 / (object2.xcor()**2 + object2.ycor()**2)
        rad = math.radians(object2.towards(0, 0))
        object2_xvel += math.cos(rad) * distance
        object2_yvel += math.sin(rad) * distance
        object2.setposition(object2.xcor() + object2_xvel, object2.ycor() + object2_yvel)

        distance = (1000 / (object1.xcor() ** 2 + object1.ycor() ** 2))
        rad = math.radians(object1.towards(0, 0))
        object1_xvel += math.cos(rad) * distance
        object1_yvel += math.sin(rad) * distance
        object1.setposition(object1.xcor() + object1_xvel, object1.ycor() + object1_yvel)

        # move `spacecraft` with `earth`
        object3.setposition(object3.xcor() + object2_xvel, object3.ycor() + object2_yvel)

        #distance = ( (object3.xcor()**2)-(object2.xcor()**2) ) + ( (object3.ycor()**2)-(object2.ycor()**2) )
        distance = 1000/3441 # constant value
        rad = math.radians(object3.towards(object2.xcor(), object2.ycor()))
        object3_xvel += math.cos(rad) * distance
        object3_yvel += math.sin(rad) * distance
        object3.setposition(object3.xcor() + object3_xvel, object3.ycor() + object3_yvel)


way_to_orbit(620, 0, mars, "red")
way_to_orbit(375, 0, earth, "blue")
way_to_orbit(436, 0, spacecraft, "green")

ellipse(mars, earth, spacecraft)

turtle.done()
```

---

Long time ago I made something similar but moving in `circles` instead of `eclipses` and it looks better.

For `spacecraft` I use value instead calculations to get better effect. Every object add different value to angle to make different speed.

```
import turtle
import math

def move_to_orbit(x,y, item, color):
    item.dot(50, "yellow")
    item.color("white")
    item.fillcolor(color)
    item.shape("circle")
    item.penup()
    item.setposition(x, y)
    item.pendown()


def move_on_orbits(object1, object2, object3):

    object1_angle = 0
    object2_angle = 0
    object3_angle = 0

    while True:

        object1_angle += .2
        rad = math.radians(object1_angle)
        x = object1.xcor()
        y = object1.ycor()
        center_x = 0 # sun
        center_y = 0 # sun
        distance = ((x-center_x)**2 + (y-center_y)**2)**.5 # calculation are precise 
        #distance = 420 # distance to sun
        x = center_x + math.cos(rad) * distance 
        y = center_y + math.sin(rad) * distance
        object1.setposition(x, y)

        object2_angle += .1
        rad = math.radians(object2_angle)
        x = object2.xcor()
        y = object2.ycor()
        center_x = 0 # sun
        center_y = 0 # sun
        distance = ((x-center_x)**2 + (y-center_y)**2)**.5 # calculation are precise 
        #distance = 175 # distance to sun
        x = center_x + math.cos(rad) * distance 
        y = center_y + math.sin(rad) * distance
        object2.setposition(x, y)

        object3_angle += 2
        rad = math.radians(object3_angle)
        x = object3.xcor()
        y = object3.ycor()
        center_x = object2.xcor() # earth
        center_y = object2.ycor() # earth
        #distance = ((x-center_x)**2 + (y-center_y)**2)**.5 calculation are NOT precise
        distance = 30 # distance to earth
        x = center_x + math.cos(rad) * distance 
        y = center_y + math.sin(rad) * distance
        object3.setposition(x, y)


mars = turtle.Turtle()
earth = turtle.Turtle()
spacecraft = turtle.Turtle()


move_to_orbit(420, 0, mars, "red")
move_to_orbit(175, 0, earth, "blue")
move_to_orbit(205, 0, spacecraft, "green")

move_on_orbits(mars, earth, spacecraft)


turtle.done()
```